# How to delimit a string field into two different numeric columns in R

Tags: r, regex, substring, delimiter

I have a dataframe which has a text field that captures how long a person has stayed in a city. It is in the format of `y year(s) m month(s)` with y and m being numeric. If the person has lived in the city less than a year, then the value will only be in the format `m months`

I want to convert this column into two separate numeric columns, one of them showing the years lived and the other showing the months lived.

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Time.in.current.role = c("1 year 1 month", "11 
months", 
"3 years 11 months", "1 year 1 month", "8 months"), City = 
c("Philadelphia", 
"Seattle", "Washington D.C.", "Ashburn", "Cork, Ireland")), .Names = 
c("Time.in.current.role", 
"City"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

My desire dataframe looks like:

```
result <- structure(list(Year = c(1, 0, 3, 1, 0), Month = c(1, 11, 
11, 
1, 8), City = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Ashburn", 
"Cork, Ireland", "Philadelphia", "Seattle", "Washington D.C."
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Year", "Month", "City"), row.names 
= c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I was thinking of using grep to locate which rows have the substring "year" in it and which rows have the substring "month" in it. But after that, I am having trouble trying to get the number that appropriately associates to either "year" or "month".

*** EDIT ***
In my original post, I forgot to account for the case that it is possible to have only `y year(s)`. Here is the new original dataframe and desired dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Time.in.current.role = c("1 year 1 month", "11 
months", 
"3 years 11 months", "1 year 1 month", "8 months", "2 years"), 
City = c("Philadelphia", "Seattle", "Washington D.C.", "Ashburn", 
"Cork, Ireland", "Washington D.C.")), .Names = 
c("Time.in.current.role", 
"City"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 18L), class = 
"data.frame")

result <- structure(list(Year = c(1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2), Month = c(1, 11, 
11, 
1, 8, 0), City = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L), .Label = 
c("Ashburn", 
"Cork, Ireland", "Philadelphia", "Seattle", "Washington D.C."
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Year", "Month", "City"), row.names 
= c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This defines a function `extr` (also see alternative definition at end) that will extract from its first argument the match to the second argument's capture group, i.e. the match to the part of the regular expression within parentheses.  Then the match is converted to numeric, or if the pattern is not found 0 is returned.

It is only 3 lines of code, has a pleasing symmetry in how it handles the year and month and can handle not only year and month but also just year and just month.  It allows junk before the y and m such as the \n shown in the sample data in the question.

```
library(gsubfn)

extr <- function(x, pat) strapply(x, pat, as.numeric, empty = 0, simplify = TRUE)
transform(df, Year = extr(Time.in.current.role, "(\\d+) +\\W*y"),
              Month = extr(Time.in.current.role, "(\\d+) +\\W*m"))
```

giving (for the data frame defined in the question):

```
  Time.in.current.role            City Year Month
1       1 year 1 month    Philadelphia    1     1
2          11 \nmonths         Seattle    0    11
3    3 years 11 months Washington D.C.    3    11
4       1 year 1 month         Ashburn    1     1
5             8 months   Cork, Ireland    0     8
```

Note that `strapply` uses the tcl regex engine by default but if tcltk does not work on your system then use this slightly longer version of `extr` or even better would be to fix your installation since tcltk is a base package and if that does not work your R installation is broken.

```
extr <- function(x, pat) {
  sapply(strapply(x, pat, as.numeric), function(x) if (is.null(x)) 0 else x)
}
```

Comment: It seems like when I run this solution, I get the following error: 
`Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`

Comment: I can't reproduce that with the input in the question.  What input did you use?

Comment: I am running it with the sample df. I think it may be a problem of loading the gsubfn package since when I install it, I get a warning that it isn't able to load a shared object/library

Comment: There is likely something wrong with your R installation and you are missing tcl/tk.  In that case use the alternate `extr` shown at the end (or even better would be to fix your R installation).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
z = regmatches(x = df$Time.in.current.role, gregexpr("\\d+", df$Time.in.current.role))
years = sapply(z, function(x){ifelse(length(x)==1, 0, x[1])})
months = sapply(z, function(x){ifelse(length(x)==1, x[1], x[2])})
```

This gives:

```
> years
[1] "1" "0" "3" "1" "0"
> months
[1] "1"  "11" "11" "1"  "8"
```

This method works if there are  or two numbers. If there is only one, this assumes that it corresponds to months.  A case where this does not works is, for example, `"5 years"`.

In this case you could do the following:

```
m = regmatches(x = df$Time.in.current.role, gregexpr("\\d+ m", df$Time.in.current.role))
y = regmatches(x = df$Time.in.current.role, gregexpr("\\d+ y", df$Time.in.current.role))
y2 = sapply(y, function(x){ifelse(length(x)==0,0,gsub("\\D+","",x))})
m2 = sapply(m, function(x){ifelse(length(x)==0,0,gsub("\\D+","",x))})
```

Example:

```
> df
  Time.in.current.role            City
1       1 year 1 month    Philadelphia
2            11 months         Seattle
3    3 years 11 months Washington D.C.
4       1 year 1 month         Ashburn
5             8 months   Cork, Ireland
6              5 years           Miami

> y2
[1] "1" "0" "3" "1" "0" "5"
> m2
[1] "1"  "11" "11" "1"  "8"  "0"
```

Comment: yes, I did not account for the case where there is only year, but no months, but that data does exist in my dataset. Thank you for noticing this!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use the package `splitstackshape` to split the column in two. To do that you would first need to set a delimiter between years and months with gsub, then remove all characters and then use `cSplit`:

```
# replace delimiter year with ;
df$Time.in.current.role <- gsub("year", ";", df$Time.in.current.role)

# If no year was found add 0; at the beginning of the cell
df$Time.in.current.role[!grepl(";", df$Time.in.current.role)] <- paste0("0;", df$Time.in.current.role[!grepl(";", df$Time.in.current.role)])

# remove characters and whitespace
df$Time.in.current.role <- gsub("[[:alpha:]]|\\s+", "", df$Time.in.current.role)

# Split column by ;
df <- splitstackshape::cSplit(df, "Time.in.current.role", sep = ";")

# Rename new columns
colnames(df)[2:3] <- c("Year", "Month")

df
              City  Year  Month
1:    Philadelphia     1      1
2:         Seattle     0     11
3: Washington D.C.     3     11
4:         Ashburn     1      1
5:   Cork, Ireland     0      8
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick 'n dirty solution:

**Code:**

```
ym <- gsub("[^0-9|^ ]", "", df$Time.in.current.role)
ym <- gsub("^ | $", "", ym)
df$Year <- ifelse(
  grepl(" ", ym), 
  gsub("([0-9]+) .+", "\\1", ym), 
  0
)
df$Month <- gsub(".+ ([0-9]+)$", "\\1", ym)
df$Time.in.current.role <- NULL
df

             City Year Month
1    Philadelphia    1     1
2         Seattle    0    11
3 Washington D.C.    3    11
4         Ashburn    1     1
5   Cork, Ireland    0     8
```

**Words**:

- Start by deleting everything that is not a number or a space
- Delete all spaces at the start or end of string
- If the string contains two numbers *then* extract first as the year, *otherwise* `year = 0`.
- The last number is alway the month.
- Drop original column from data.frame
- Enjoy